# Error when updating a document properties using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I need to update the version number of a document in a document library in SharePoint Online. I used postman to test this. Here is the POST Request I used.

```
https://MySharePointServer/sites/MySite/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/MySite/JobApplications/Application001.docx')/ListItemAllFields
```

Request Headers

```
Accept          : application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization   : 'My Authorization Code Here'
X-HTTP-Method   : MERGE
If-Match        : *
Content-Type    : application/json;odata=verbose
X-RequestDigest : 'MyRequestDigestCodeHere'
```

Request Body

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.JobApplicationsItem' }, 'OData__UIVersionString': '4.0' }
```

But when I send this request I always get the following response.

```
{
"error": {
"code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
"message": {
  "lang": "en-US",
  "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
  }
 }
}
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing request digest in the header

Comment: Sorry, I missed it in my question. I already added that in my request.

Comment: How did you find that? using `_api/contextinfo`?

Comment: Yes. Using _api/contextinfo

Comment: SharePoint usually assigns the version number to the item on the server when you update it, why are you trying to manually assign it?

Comment: I need to update it to make it a major version. Such as 3.6 into 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't update the Version number directly.

To make a major version you have to use the [CheckIn method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileCheckIn) with checkInType=1.

Or depending on your list [Publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FilePublish)+[Approve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FilePublish)

Comment: '/approve' just updated the minor version to the next major version which was exactly what I was searching for..! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the version number manually (even with the server object model you can only 'get' the version property, [no setter identified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.majorversion.aspx)); just doing a major version check-in should accomplish what you're looking for and let SharePoint figure out what version number to provide though:

```
function majorCheckInAsync(fileUrl, comment) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + fileUrl + "')/CheckOut()",
        type: "POST",
        headers:  {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    }).fail(failHandler).then(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + fileUrl + "')/CheckIn(comment='" + comment +"', checkintype=1)",
            type: "POST",
            headers:  {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            }
        }).fail(failHandler).then(function(data) {
            dfd.resolve(data);
        });
    });

    return dfd.promise();

    function failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            dfd.reject(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
}
```

Call this with something like:

```
majorCheckInAsync("/Shared%20Documents/my%20new%20file.txt", "Checkin from REST")
    .then(function(data) { console.log("item checked in") });
```

Note the `checkintype` in my REST url is set to `1` -- this corresponds to a `MajorCheckIn` in the [`SP.CheckInType` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileCheckIn):

> checkInType
>
> Type: **Int32**
>
> The **SP.CheckinType** for the file: MinorCheckIn = 0; MajorCheckIn = 1; OverwriteCheckIn = 2.

Doing a major check in is what will give us the `x.0` major version number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John. I tried your approach. But the document should be in 'checked-out' before we do this.

Comment: @JanakaLP if the document is already checked out you can just skip the `CheckOut` endpoint call and proceed directly to `CheckIn`, the technique would still be the same - and I realize now you didn't even ask in the context of JavaScript but the approach should be similar

Comment: Thank you very much John. Just replaced the '/CheckIn' in the end of the URL with '/Approve' and it updated the minor version to the next major version successfully..! Thanks again.